# How to make a chart with highcharts, load data from API

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts, timestamp

I am a new programmer and this is my first time using highcharts.
I have code like this using highstocks library too:

```js
Highcharts.getJSON('https://gmlews.com/api/data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var accelero_x = [],
    timestamp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    accelero_x.push(data[i].accelero_x);
    timestamp.push(data[i].timestamp);
  }
  console.log(accelero_x);
  console.log(timestamp);
  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Accelero X'
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Accelero X',
      data: accelero_x,
      type: 'spline',
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

You can see the full running code on : https://jsfiddle.net/estri012/y1usoxd7/1/

The problem is how to make the x-axes based on my timestamp?

New problem after get the x-axes right is : in my api, some of the last  data is in 19March. But on the chart the last data shows 18March not 19March. Actually there is no one single data on 18March in my API. You can check the api on the URL above. Meanwhile the other data before those are showing the right date on the chart.
This is the capture of the chart : 
[image: Chart]

Comment: can't you just modify their example to your needs? https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/spline

Comment: @Phil I've tried and edit my question. The problem right now how to make x-axes based on my own timestamp from API. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your data to the format required by Highcharts, in your case - an array of arrays or an array of objcts ({ x, y }).

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://gmlews.com/api/data', function(data) {
  var seriesData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    seriesData.push([
      new Date(data[i].timestamp).getTime(),
      data[i].accelero_x
    ]);
  }

  // Create the chart
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82vqcwsr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data

Comment: I have a problem, on the chart the last three data shown 18 March, but actually in my API it is 19 March. Why this is happen? The other data is fine. Just those data which not showing the right date

Comment: Hi @Estri. P Lestari, Could you provide me with some online example that shows the problem?

Comment: I update my question with the screencapture of the chart. You can check my API on https://gmlews.com/api/data

Comment: I update my code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/estri012/rhon7g3b/16/ . But still didn't work. And actually the time shows like this in API : 2020-03-15T11:46:10+07:00 . So on the chart it should be 15March 11:46, but it shows 15 March 04:46. And the last three data still show 18 March on chart. The datetime in my API and on the chart are not showing the same result. How to fix it?

Comment: I solved it! I need to disable the UTC timezone function on the chart so my timestamp will be look like the same as my API data